# Add input values to a dynamic <tr> in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to add text field value to a dynamic `<tr>`.

new-betting.component.html

```
<input type="number" [formControl]="betOption3" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal">

<tr *ngFor="let row of selectedOptions$ | async">
   <td>{{ row.code.value }}</td>
   <td>{{ row.desc.value }}</td>
   <td>{{ row.amount.value }}</td>
</tr>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-round waves-effect waves-light m-1" id="addnewrecord" (click)="addRow()">Add Bet</button>
```

new-betting.components.ts

```
betOption = new FormControl();
betOption2 = new FormControl();
betOption3 = new FormControl();
options$ = new BehaviorSubject([{ id: 1, value: 'Mark Verndom' }, { id: 2, value: 'Jacob Brown' }, { id: 3, value: 'Steve Rogurs' }]);
options2$ = new BehaviorSubject([{ id: 1, value: 'CSN1' }, { id: 2, value: 'CIA5' }, { id: 3, value: 'CSI7' }]);

addRow() {
if (!this.betOption.value) {
    return;
}
if (!this.betOption2.value) {
  return;
}
const yourSelectedObject = this.options$.value.find(el => el.id === Number(this.betOption.value));
const yourSelectedObject2 = this.options2$.value.find(el2 => el2.id === Number(this.betOption2.value));
const yourSelectedObject3 = this.options2$.value.find(el3 => el3.id === Number(this.betOption3.value));
this.selectedOptions$.next([...this.selectedOptions$.value, {desc: yourSelectedObject, code: yourSelectedObject2, amount: yourSelectedObject3}]);

}
```

previously I have added two `<select>` values to this dynamic `<tr>`. they are working well. But it is difficult to add this text field to `<tr>`. I am fresher for Angular. Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Set template reference variables on input and pass its value on button click. Catch value in **addRow(betOption3typeValue) {}** function.

```
<input #betOption3type="number" [formControl]="betOption3" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-round waves-effect waves-light m-1" id="addnewrecord" (click)="addRow(betOption3.value)">Add Bet</button>
```

Comment: `addRow(betOption3typeValue) {
    if (!this.betOption.value) {
        return;
    }
    if (!this.betOption2.value) {
      return;
    }
    if (!this.betOption3.value) {
      return;
    }
    const yourSelectedObject = this.options$.value.find(el => el.id === Number(this.betOption.value));
    const yourSelectedObject2 = this.options2$.value.find(el2 => el2.id === Number(this.betOption2.value));
    this.selectedOptions$.next([...this.selectedOptions$.value, {desc: yourSelectedObject, code: yourSelectedObject2, amount: betOption3typeValue}]);`

Comment: When I try to change with your changes and `addRow(betOption3typeValue)`. project dose not run...what is the wrong with above method?

Comment: What error comes in browser console or at build time ?

Comment: I am not getting error msg. But page is not loading. Can u mention here how `addRow()` should be changed?

Comment: This may be because of scope of template reference variables. Check my other answer using ngModel,

Answer (score 0):

U can try [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/edit) table

OR

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of selectedOptions$ | async">
  <td><input [(NgModel)]="row.code.value" /></td>
  <td><input [(NgModel)]="row.code.value" /></td>
  <td><input [(NgModel)]="row.amount.value" /></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach by two way binding using **ngModel**. NgModel is part of the angular "FormsModule" and has to be imported into your module

```
<input [(ngModel)]="betOption3type" type="number" [formControl]="betOption3" class="form-control allownumericwithoutdecimal">
```

In class define betOption3type variable.

```
betOption3type = "";
```

This variables holds input value and can be used in addRow().

```
this.selectedOptions$.next([...this.selectedOptions$.value, {desc: yourSelectedObject, code: yourSelectedObject2, amount: this.betOption3type}]);
```